# Best way to distribute Android Library

Tags: android, jar, android-studio, android-library

What is the best way to distribute android Library. I dont want the user to see my code, library has images and layout xml. Here is my  understanding. Please correct if I am wrong.

- If I make Jar then I cannot add res folder as part of my jar. (I know using progurad is an option to obfuscate code.)
- If I publish aar I have to make my repo public?

So my question is that how can I distribute my library to user without giving access to my code while adding images and layout files as part of that library.

Answer (score 2):

There is [`aar`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) format which was exactly created for libraries distribution.

Comment: What I read was that aar is simply a zip file. So my question is that can I add resource and layout in it? And will my code be private. If I have to publish aar?

Comment: @NaumanAfzaal you can add resources and layouts. To protect you code you can obfuscate it using `ProGuard`. By the way there is no 100% guarantee of protection.

Comment: Is there anyway to publish aar of private repo?

Comment: @NaumanAfzaal `aar` is just a file. You can publish it wherever you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jar
U may have to get the image file and res files through a constructor if that is null use default

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't, even if it's a jar there is a tons of tools to reverse engineer it ([one of the tools](http://bytecode.club/))

The only thing you can do is obfuscated your code so it turns to unreadable code. Read here about proGuard with android([proGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html))

For the distribution part with res I recommend using gradle. For example [Jake Wharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton) has a library named [butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife).
He distributed it using gradle so the user could just add

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
```

in his gradle files and be good to go.

Another example with res files distrbuted in gradle is the [android support libs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/res/) which can be grabbed by adding:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am using proGuard. But I want to know how can I add images and layout as part of my library

Comment: as far as we're using the market-oriented languages (java,c#) you simply can't hide your code but it's not the same of there old mother (c++) which you can close it

Comment: If I publish my library I think I have to make my code public. Secondly what if I want to pack layout xml and images as part of my library?

Comment: Is there anyway to publish aar of private repo?

Comment: @NaumanAfzaal yes you can publish it to maven central to be accessible through gradle check this article http://zserge.com/blog/gradle-maven-publish.html